# ASIHTTPRequest, project error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting this error, don't know what is the solution to it

```
Ld /Users/Omer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoginTest-eibsbylnvmiovwhavrqixbxjpvbm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LoginTest.app/LoginTest normal i386
    cd /Users/Omer/Documents/development/LoginTest
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/Omer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoginTest-eibsbylnvmiovwhavrqixbxjpvbm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Omer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoginTest-eibsbylnvmiovwhavrqixbxjpvbm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Omer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoginTest-eibsbylnvmiovwhavrqixbxjpvbm/Build/Intermediates/LoginTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LoginTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/LoginTest.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -lz -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework UIKit -o /Users/Omer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoginTest-eibsbylnvmiovwhavrqixbxjpvbm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LoginTest.app/LoginTest

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_GHAssertTrue", referenced from:
      -[VektorViewController testAuthentication] in VektorViewController.o
  "_GHAssertNil", referenced from:
      -[VektorViewController testAuthentication] in VektorViewController.o
  "_GHAssertFalse", referenced from:
      -[VektorViewController testAuthentication] in VektorViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to build a project and not run unit tests then you need to remove the test cases from your main project. If your are building the test project then you will need to include the [GHUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) project.